# How to achive a Listview layout as shown in picture?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

[image]

How can I get a `listview` layout like this as shown in the image above? The `listview is scrollable` on the left hand side and on the right side these are the items which we get after clicking on the listview item.

I have searched a lot but I cannot get how to achieve layout like this. Please guide me.

Comment: Looks like a master detail view. ca be achieved with the help of fragments

Comment: @Raghunandan can you explain a bit more..!! Thank you

Comment: http://inducesmile.com/android/android-fragment-masterdetail-flow-tutorial-in-android-studio/http://inducesmile.com/android/android-fragment-masterdetail-flow-tutorial-in-android-studio/

Comment: Aside: "Seasonings" has been misspelled in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
  
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  //////ListView
  
  </LinearLayout>
  
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  
      ///It's detail
  </LinearLayout>
  
  
  </LinearLayout>
```

```
  put these in scroll view
```

Answer (score 0):

That screen uses fragments and not ListView. as Raghunandan said.

You may refer to the link he provided.

You can also refer to this one - http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial